How to get elements after jquery page changes (I got always the same)
I was using a jquery library to reordering tables (here the link of a fiddle).
After sorting I want to gives attributes to elements on reordered table (like id=line1,id=line2 etc), but after updating by jquery like
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tofsjonas/sortable@latest/sortable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tofsjonas/sortable@latest/sortable.min.js"></script>

$(document).on("click","table",function(e) {
    const table = document.querySelectorAll('#tablea')[0];
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        row.cells[0].setAttribute('reordered', i); //testing attribute
    }
    console.log(table.rows[1].cells[1].outerText); //it's 1 because the first line is the header
});

I got always the same result.
Like the page was not changed.
If you search the first line you got always the first line in previous page content.
I putted also the Javascript code after the code where it's called the library JS that refreshes the table.
Why this and how to solve it.
TNX
EDIT: The table it's a big table with more than 30000 line (if you want to replicate the complete example) and the JS reordering seem to be executed before the script “sortable“.
PS. As now I don't want to split it in pages and I want it only on a page, so focus on the JS code and not on other solutions server side. Tnx again

Tnx @Jaromanda X 1.2.3 Code updated with $(document).on("click so there's the jquery in the code, added sorting and attibute giving in the code. In the previous version was not sorting because was a testing code. Now something happening. But why i got a wrong result?

@Jaromanda X "but the fiddle seems to work without issue". MMMM should be a different version of the library. Are u sure?

@Jaromanda X "despite not having the code you posted in the question. What is the relationship between the fiddle and the code you put in the question?" When the table it's ordered i want a table with new "reodered" id

@Jaromanda X Really i'm not using the fiddle but i'm testing on my computer. And also if i have to be honest i'm using an other library (js file) but i don't know if i find it online. Wait a minute.

Ok, found it. It's https://github.com/tofsjonas/sortable Now trying to make an example (it's a big table. it's crashing the browser. wait a minute)

The fiddle should be this https://jsfiddle.net/0me83u5L/2/ i have made it in a minute, so click. If something wrong sorry.

"you see the error when you click a header?" "for a start, yo probably wanted const t = document.querySelector('#tablea>tbody'); - and you don't want to console.log(row)" yes you ok, the code it's a little confused. I'm trying to updating it. I can't post the real table bacause it's full of private data. I have done it in a small time like u see.

"the real table is irrelevant ... the errors are in your real code" Yes man. You're posting before i can update. Drining a beer and restarting.

Ok. I don't quote more your comments in the posts everytime. It was for who it's reading. Think a good fiddle for testing it's https://jsfiddle.net/0me83u5L/8/

No i don't see an error because the table it's not finded by e.target. So if u click the header the script does not give to the table attributes

The fiddle gives as error <a class='gotoLine' href='#90:17'>90:17</a> TypeError: can't access property \&quot;cells\&quot;, e.target.row is undefined. It's the only error I see and it's because the table it's not finded by e.target as written before

https://jsfiddle.net/0me83u5L/9/ the last one. But the absurd thing it's that it works very well. I removed e.target.row so no more problems. But in my browser it's not the same as in fiddle. The table it's reordered with ids like before. I don't know why (should be because it's a big table). My head it's going mad.

the real issue is that nowhere have you posted a concise (minimal) version of the actual code you are having an issue with - i.e. in the question, not in a fiddle for a start - I've removed my comments as this is getting nowhere. I would suggest you try to show, in the question a minimal example of what you are actually doing

The code it's the same as it posted in the fiddle. Exactly. The table it's reordered, but the reordered attribute it's make on the line of the table before it's reordered. That is.

https://jsfiddle.net/qwr8cs2o/3/ Still not having the same result in the browser. (it's a very big table and since it's updated the page it take a long time). It's like the script it's executed before the reordering.

it looks like the script is executed AFTER the reordering to me - rows[1] is definitely the first non header row

It's exactly like u wrote. Looks like this. But the script it's ordered in the page after the github library (js file) it' loaded so it have to be executed before. Anyway I don't understand the be behavior. Yeah rows[1] it's definitely the first non header row but the problem it's another one . Should be because the real table it's very big. Someone that knows how to adjust this?

If u want to replicate it put in the table 60.000 lines. The computer it's a performign computer, so also 30.000 are goods. It takes 3 seconds of delay before updating and i got the last line rather than the first in console.log. It's like javascript/jquery code executing it's unordered.

what is that library you are using

@Jaromanda X The library i'm using it's the same as in the fiddle on the last link u read in the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/qwr8cs2o/3/ => https://github.com/tofsjonas/sortable

OK, what you want to do is add your script before loading the library - then your script will run before the library - like this - I'm using .dataset in that code, but that's not relevant, you can use your setAttribute stuff instead

@Jaromanda X No, exactly the opposite. I want to add the script after the library. The library has to reorder the table by clicking on it, then the mini-jquerycode written after has to add attributes on the reordered table taking a line a time while executing. I don't know the function .dataset. Post your answer with your code so i test it. I dont have seen it the link. Wait a minute. I test it. PS. In the exaple use AAAA for the first line and BBBB for the second etc. It's easier to look like this[https://jsfiddle.net/6asbftjc/]

https://jsfiddle.net/6asbftjc/1/ ABSURD!!!! WITH YOUR CODE IT'S WORKING. THE ATTRIBUTE IT'S CORRECTLY ABSIGNED. I DON'T KNOW WHY THIS. Can you explain the behavior?

Perhaps because my code only looks at the tbody ignoring the thead? Though, it seems you are confused as to what order the values should be .. with your code, the order of values is always increasing, with my code the order of those  is what it was BEFORE the sort - which now you say is correct, but two comments ago you said was not what you wanted. Perhaps the issue is that you have never described what the result should be

I think that should be the real thing. Infact the only thing that changes in the table it's the body and not thead. Looks good. @Jaromanda X Man u the best one. However it doesn't solve many of my other problems. For example when I insert new code into a page and try to process it with javascript. But that's not the question. Post your answer so I can give you a thumbs up. Good code man. The table it's correctly sorted.

OK. After trying, your magic it's the document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {. If you use this the code works well also with the code in the question. My problem was $(document).on("click","table",function(e) { that it's a jquery function. On the contrary your function uses a pure javascript. I don't know why the jquery it's has this behavior. Anyway, well done. You solved a problem for me. Post your answer. Thumb up for u.

By the way - are you using firefox? Because Firefox takes about 3 to 4 seconds to sort 30000 rows, as you stated - Chrome takes half a second! Just so you know

As for not using jQuery - I avoid it at all costs - it's pretty much only useful for legacy code or legacy browsers and some animations may be easier to write with it. In all other regards, it's slow and too forgiving of bad code at times (end rant) - not that your code was bad

Nono. I'n not using Firefox or Google Chrome. For now i'm on Opera. I know that Chrome it's the best one, but for some reason i don't have it. Anyway, it takes 3 to 4 seconds like you write. Post your answer. You have a thumb up. Here the code working: https://jsfiddle.net/2fham6cs/

What you wrote about Jquery it's not the same I think. Jquery it's easier and simplify very much the javascript code that sometimes should be incredible hard (and has also animations included like you wrote). I think it's not a problem of how mutch time requires execution, but only that the javascript addEventListener it's executer before the $(document) jquery selector. Anyway are more than 30000 rows. Over 60000. Sometimes over 100000. POST YOUR ANSWER MAAANNNN

I won't post an answer as I still don't understand what you wanted - the fact you say it works is even more confusing. You are allowed to post an answer to your own question.

????? @Jaromanda X You solved that. There's an answer made by me for someone who reads. The code works and i'm not confused about. What i wanted it's reorder the table with the library and then give an attribute to the rows. If you want i'm waiting to your answer for a thumb up. If you don't want to post an answer to the question thanks the same. Talking to you solved my problems. Looks good. Understood. 'By Man

After a long discussion in comments, thanks to @Jaromanda X the code works by replacing
$(document).on("click","table",function(e) {
with
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
I don't know why this. Should be like sayed in commets because the addEventListener it's a javascript function that is executed before the Jquery.
Here the fiddle working (tested on 40000 lines on my browser): https://jsfiddle.net/2fham6cs
If he want to takes a thumb up, the answer to the question for mental honesty it's yours.
